# Sorting a date column in CGridView with CArrayDataProvider

Tags: php, yii

I'm using a CGridView on a website to display data provided via a CArrayDataProvider. Reason for this is, that the data is cumulated across different tables and enriched with additional computed columns.
Sorting and Filtering is generally working fine with this code (... are omitted columns):

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'produkt-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>new CArrayDataProvider($betroffeneProdukte, array(
            'sort' => array(
                'attributes' => array(
                    'bezeichnung',
                    'datum',
                    ...
                ),
            ),
            'pagination' => false,
        )),
    'enableSorting' => true,
        'columns'=>array(
            array(
                'name'=>'bezeichnung',
                'header'=>'Bezeichnung',
                'value'=>'$data["bezeichnung"]',
            ),
            array(
                'name'=>'datum',
                'header'=>'datum',
                'value'=>'$data["datum"]',
            ),
            ...
        ),

));
```

Problem is the date column. It is sorting as a string like this (German format):
01.10.2012, 03.08.2012, 10.01.2012, 15.02.2012, ...

I would like to sort it correctly like this of course:
10.01.2012, 15.02.2012, 03.08.2012, 01.10.2012, ...

Anyone got an idea for me?

Comment: how is that date being stored in the database i.e. what data type are you using to store the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to send in a raw date / datetime string to your CArrayDataProvider from your data source and then format it with the CGridView instead:

```
array(
    'name'=>'datum',
    'header'=>'datum',
    'value'=>'$data["datum"]',
    'type'=>'date',
),
```

It looks like your problem is that Yii thinks your date is a string (instead of a date).  If you shift to providing the DataProvider a date, the sorting may work itself out.

Comment: did you try this? does it work that way? by just specifying type date?

Comment: no, i didn't try it.  I don't think that my suggestion will totally fix the problem, but should point him in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Actually, the 'datum' column in my example is a string, because I have to use virtual attributes to format dates correctly in German across my application. Now I use the original date-column from the database and format it in the view like this:

```
array(
  'name'=>'datecolumn',
  'header'=>'Eingangsdatum',
  'value'=>'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->formatDateTime(strtotime($data["datecolumn"]), "medium", null)',
),
```

=> voila, German display, correctly being able to sort.

Comment: Instead of using a dateFormatter (which I did initially as well), there's a relatively little known way to get your CGridView to auto format columns for you.  See more here: https://github.com/samdark/a-guide-to-yii-grids-lists-and-data-providers/blob/master/grid-columns.md  It saves me tons of time! :-)

Comment: @acorncom yes, I second this.  Specifying 'type'=>'datetime' in the column definition is the way to do it when your underlying data is a datetime.